# Questions from Chapter 13 of The Hound of the Baskervilles

Tags: meaning-in-context

Quote:

To all the world he was the man of violence, half animal and half demon; but to her he always remained the little wilful boy of her own girlhood, the child who had clung to her hand. Evil indeed is the man who has not one woman to mourn him.

Does "Evil indeed is the man who has not one woman to mourn him." suggest that this man cannot be taken as evil since at least he had one woman to mourn him?

Comment: I'm not sure your *exact* paraphrasing truly reflects the intent of the final sentence. It's not so much asserting *this particular person is not truly evil* as claiming that *anyone whose death **isn't mourned by even one woman** must be truly evil*. Which is a bit extreme, and certainly doesn't bode well for gay men! (Assuming that *usually*, men don't die before their mothers, obviously! :)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: No. 'Evil _indeed_' corresponds to 'one of the most evil imaginable'. 'He' may be evil, but not as evil as these men.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - IIRC this woman was the convict's big sister, not his mother.

Comment: @KateBunting: Yes, but every man has a mother (who presumably would normally mourn the passing of her son if he predeceased her), whereas not everyone has a *sister*. "Her" in OP's first sentence may well be his sister, but the second sentence makes a much more general assertion about ***all*** (potentially evil) men, and it's *that* I'm saying is "a bit extreme". Anyway - Edwin is quite correct that the cited text doesn't exactly mean the subject ***isn't*** "evil". It means he's not ***a truly extreme example*** of an evil person (because of how his sister feels about him).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, it's a bit like the proverb "It's an ill wind that blows no one any good".

Comment: Incidentally, OP's last line is fallacious. Given: if no woman mourns him, then he is evil. Improper inference: if one woman mourns him, then he is not evil. This is fallacious because it may be that all men un-mourned by a woman are evil, and additionally some men mourned by a woman are evil.